# Failed to get response from nginx ingress controller

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, curl, nginx-ingress

I deploy an Nginx Ingress Controller with 1 replica, exposed by Nodeport.

```
[root@test-120 test]# kubectl get pod -n ingress -owide
NAME                                           READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE   IP            NODE       NOMINATED NODE   READINESS GATES
nginx-ingress-nginx-ingress-5b84865587-srtvt   1/1     Running   0          46m   10.96.154.5   test-120   <none>           <none>
```

And deploy an EchoServer on each node.

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: echoserver
spec:
  replicas: 3
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: echoserver
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: echoserver
    spec:
      affinity:
        podAntiAffinity:
          requiredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution:
            - labelSelector:
                matchExpressions:
                  - key: "app"
                    operator: In
                    values:
                      - echoserver
              topologyKey: "kubernetes.io/hostname"
      containers:
        - image: ealen/echo-server
          imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
          name: echoserver
          ports:
            - containerPort: 80
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: echoserver
spec:
  ports:
    - port: 80
      targetPort: 80
      protocol: TCP
  selector:
    app: echoserver
---
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: test
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "nginx"
spec:
  rules:
    - host: "*.amazonaws.com.cn"
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /
            pathType: ImplementationSpecific
            backend:
              service:
                name: echoserver
                port:
                  number: 80
```

**When try to access the ingress on my PC**

`curl http://test.amazonaws.com.cn`

**I can't get the response, and here is the Nginx Ingress log**

`kubectl logs -f nginx-ingress-nginx-ingress-5b84865587-srtvt -ningress`

```
2021/09/08 14:00:04 [warn] 134#134: *21 upstream server temporarily disabled while reading response header from upstream, client: 10.88.0.1, server: *.amazonaws.com.cn, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://10.96.175.3:80/", host: "test.amazonaws.com.cn"
2021/09/08 14:00:04 [error] 134#134: *21 upstream timed out (110: Connection timed out) while reading response header from upstream, client: 10.88.0.1, server: *.amazonaws.com.cn, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://10.96.175.3:80/", host: "test.amazonaws.com.cn"
```

**With the logs, I try to enter the Ingress Pod and access the Upstream Server, it works fine.**

`kubectl exec -it nginx-ingress-nginx-ingress-5b84865587-srtvt -ningress -- curl http://10.96.175.3:80`

output:

```
{"host":{"hostname":"10.96.113.66","ip":"::ffff:10.96.154.5","ips":[]},"http":{"method":"GET","baseUrl":"","originalUrl":"/","protocol":"http"},"request":{"params":{"0":"/"},"query":{},"cookies":{},"body":{},"headers":{"host":"10.96.113.66","user-agent":"curl/7.64.0","accept":"*/*"}},"environment":{"PATH":"/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin","HOSTNAME":"echoserver-7d74b86448-4zjsf","ECHOSERVER_PORT":"tcp://10.111.205.38:80","ECHOSERVER_PORT_80_TCP_PORT":"80","KUBERNETES_SERVICE_PORT_HTTPS":"443","KUBERNETES_PORT":"tcp://10.96.0.1:443","KUBERNETES_PORT_443_TCP":"tcp://10.96.0.1:443","KUBERNETES_PORT_443_TCP_ADDR":"10.96.0.1","ECHOSERVER_SERVICE_PORT":"80","KUBERNETES_SERVICE_PORT":"443","KUBERNETES_PORT_443_TCP_PROTO":"tcp","KUBERNETES_PORT_443_TCP_PORT":"443","ECHOSERVER_PORT_80_TCP_PROTO":"tcp","ECHOSERVER_PORT_80_TCP_ADDR":"10.111.205.38","KUBERNETES_SERVICE_HOST":"10.96.0.1","ECHOSERVER_SERVICE_HOST":"10.111.205.38","ECHOSERVER_PORT_80_TCP":"tcp://10.111.205.38:80","NODE_VERSION":"14.17.1","YARN_VERSION":"1.22.5","HOME":"/root"}}
```

So I want to find out why the nginx ingress controller can't get response from upstream server `http://10.96.175.3:80` when I curl it on PC, but it can get response by curl from itself.

Comment: I dont think http://test.amazonaws.com.cn resolves to your ingress from your local.

Comment: This is the pod ip range, which is not available from your local PC. This is range is private inside the cluster. You need to use port forwarding with kubectl or use a service you call with an (public) IP address.

Comment: I have changed my PC's hosts file, so the `test.amazonaws.com.cn` can point to the EC2.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I'm having the same exact issue. Curl the public IP address of the ingress from my local machine and it fails. Exec the same curl from within the ingress controller pod and the curl succeeds.